# How do I make a single-page nav? NO SCROLLING, just a nav with it's own body

Tags: javascript, html, css, single-page-application, nav

I've searched all over the Internet but it seems that there are no tutorials that teach these types of nav.

I've been trying to do recreate a movie website as an exercise and on their front page, they have this https://gph.is/g/E1W3OQq. I've searched all over the Internet and I haven't found a single tutorial. My knowledge of javascript is almost null.

I've done this https://jsfiddle.net/oViana_/gbtcLrmf/8/ so far and added the divs that I want to go on each section.

1. (PS: Don't mind the posters, I literally just searched "[Seaction Name] poster")
2. (PS: BTW, I have no idea why doesn't the nav behave like the nav on the top when I resize the page)

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4em;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.top {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.98;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
 }

li.li-top {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.li-top a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

li.li-top a:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  color: #dbdbdb;
}

li.li-top-active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

li.li-top-active a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

li.li-top-active a:hover {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.media-div {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  user-select: none;
}

.media-title {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -2.2em;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #000000;
  float: right;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: static;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 25em;
  float: left;
}

ul.media {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 75em;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 16px;
 }

li.li-media {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.li-media a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

li.li-media a:hover {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

li.li-media a:active {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

li.li-media-active {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.li-media-active a {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

.content-media {
  width: 75em;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.content-media-padding {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  height: 18em;
  width: 12em;
}

.img-container {
  height: 18em;
  width: 12em;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-container:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-title {
  width: 12em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: -0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-title-padding {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

figcaption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

figcaption a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dbdbdb;
}

.content-title:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.footer-title {
  user-select: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-txt {
  user-select: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -5em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer {
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74494548e4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="top">
      <li class="li-top-active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Series</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Animes</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="media-div">
    <ul class="media">
      <h1 class="media-title">Movies</h1>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" placeholder="Search here a movie">
        <a href="#" class="search-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <li class="li-media-active"><a href="#">Highlights</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#">Most seen</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#">Most recent added</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#">Most rated</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Highlights">
            <img  src="https://mischalke04.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/the-highlights-poster.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Highlights</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most seen">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/22/ea/3122ea91ff43732c50c9fa8c5761271f.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most seen</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most recent added">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/66/03/6e6603be280359c8a62e0f2f498242ea.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most recent added</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most rated">
            <img  src="https://d13ezvd6yrslxm.cloudfront.net/wp/wp-content/images/TFINYR-Poster-700x999.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most rated</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h1 class="footer-title">Help</h1>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Contact</h1></a>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Terms of service</h1></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by a single page nav?  the nav's you link to are different pages

Comment: You need to search for a tab navigation. This might help: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/w3css_tabulators.asp
You have hundreds of tutorials for this type of navigation. Most will required the use of JavaScript.

Comment: In your HTML, all id's must be unique, you can't have more than one id="movies-highlights"

Answer (score 0):

The link "href" will look for the element with the id that matches it's value. Check below. #Highlights will look for the element with the id of "Highlights"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74494548e4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="top">
      <li class="li-top-active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Series</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Animes</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="media-div">
    <ul class="media">
      <h1 class="media-title">Movies</h1>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" placeholder="Search here a movie">
        <a href="#" class="search-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <li class="li-media-active"><a href="#Highlights">Highlights</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#MostSeen">Most seen</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#MostRecentAdded">Most recent added</a></li>
      <li class="li-media"><a href="#MostRated">Most rated</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content-media" id="Highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Highlights">
            <img  src="https://mischalke04.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/the-highlights-poster.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Highlights</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="MostSeen">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most seen">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/22/ea/3122ea91ff43732c50c9fa8c5761271f.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="">Most seen</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="MostRecentAdded">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most recent added">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/66/03/6e6603be280359c8a62e0f2f498242ea.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most recent added</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="MostRated">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most rated">
            <img  src="https://d13ezvd6yrslxm.cloudfront.net/wp/wp-content/images/TFINYR-Poster-700x999.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most rated</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h1 class="footer-title">Help</h1>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Contact</h1></a>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Terms of service</h1></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: as for your top navbar, I prefer using bootstrap for that https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/navbar/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add this function to your js project files

```
function openTab(tabName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-media");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";  
}

openTab('movies-highlights')
```

This function, when invoked, hides all the tabs and the displays only the needed one by using `id` attribute

Then you change your nav elements from links `a` to regular buttons `button` and append some new styles to them (cause they have different default styles then links have)

Then you make sure all of your ids are unique in order to display the specific tab.

And then to each nav button you add the following attribute: `data-open="movies-highlights"`. As an argument you specify the id of the element that you want to show.

And you get this:

```js
function openTab(tabName) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("content-media");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";  
  }
  document.getElementById(tabName).style.display = "block";
}

openTab('movies-highlights')

// the following is used to make tabs active when click on them

let navButtons = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-open]')

navButtons.forEach((elem) => {
  elem.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    for (var i = 0; i < navButtons.length; i++) {
      navButtons[i].classList.remove('active')
    }
    
    e.target.classList.add('active')
    
    openTab(e.target.getAttribute('data-open'))
  })
})
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background-color: #222222;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top: 4em;
  padding: 0;
}

ul.top {
  display: block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 16px;
  opacity: 0.98;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
 }

li.li-top {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.li-top a {
  display: block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

li.li-top a:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  color: #dbdbdb;
}

li.li-top-active {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

li.li-top-active a {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
}

li.li-top-active a:hover {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

.media-div {
  padding-bottom: 1.5em;
  user-select: none;
}

.media-title {
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 2.5em;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.search-box {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 3em;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #000000;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: -2.2em;
}

.search-btn {
  color: #000000;
  float: right;
  width: 3em;
  height: 3em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  position: static;
}

.search-txt {
  border: none;
  background: none;
  outline: none;
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 1em;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 17px;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 25em;
  float: left;
}

ul.media {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 0;
   width: 75em;
   background-color: #ffffff;
   font-weight: bold;
   text-align: center;
   cursor: default;
   user-select: none;
   border: none;
   font-size: 16px;
 }

li.li-media {
  display: inline-block;
}

li.li-media button {
  display: block;
  color: #000000;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 3em;
  padding-left: 3em;
  padding-right: 3em;
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  transition: all 200ms ease-in-out;
}

li.li-media button:hover {
  background: #dbdbdb!important;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
}

li.li-media button:active {
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
}

// styles for active nav item
button[data-open].active {
  background-color: #999999;
}
button[data-open].active:hover {
  background-color: #999999 !important;
}



.content-media {
  width: 75em;
  background-color: #dbdbdb;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.content-media-padding {
  padding-bottom: 1em;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

.img {
  height: 18em;
  width: 12em;
}

.img-container {
  height: 18em;
  width: 12em;
  padding: 1em;
  transition: all ease-in-out 100ms;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img-container:hover {
  transform: scale(1.02);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.content-title {
  width: 12em;
  height: 2.5em;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2.5em;
  margin-top: -0.3em;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all ease-in-out 250ms;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.content-title-padding {
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

figcaption a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
}

figcaption a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #dbdbdb;
}

.content-title:hover {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.footer-title {
  user-select: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 3em;
  width: 5em;
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: -6em;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer-txt {
  user-select: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1em;
  margin-bottom: -5em;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.footer {
  user-select: none;
  background-color: #1d1d1d;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 3em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/74494548e4.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul class="top">
      <li class="li-top-active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Series</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Animes</a></li>
      <li class="li-top"><a href="#">Help</a></li>
    </ul>
  <div class="media-div">
    <ul class="media">
      <h1 class="media-title">Movies</h1>
      <div class="search-box">
        <input class="search-txt" type="text" placeholder="Search here a movie">
        <a href="#" class="search-btn">
          <i class="fas fa-search"></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <li class="li-media"><button data-open="movies-highlights" class="active">Highlights</button></li>
      <li class="li-media"><button data-open="movies-seen">Most seen</button></li>
      <li class="li-media"><button data-open="movies-recent">Most recent added</button></li>
      <li class="li-media"><button data-open="movies-rated">Most rated</button></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-highlights">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Highlights">
            <img  src="https://mischalke04.files.wordpress.com/2010/06/the-highlights-poster.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Highlights</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-seen">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most seen">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/31/22/ea/3122ea91ff43732c50c9fa8c5761271f.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most seen</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-recent">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most recent added">
            <img  src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/66/03/6e6603be280359c8a62e0f2f498242ea.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most recent added</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content-media" id="movies-rated">
      <div class="content-media-padding"
        <a>
          <div class="img-container" title="Most rated">
            <img  src="https://d13ezvd6yrslxm.cloudfront.net/wp/wp-content/images/TFINYR-Poster-700x999.jpg" class="img">
            <figcaption class="content-title">
              <div class="content-title-padding"
                <a href="#">Most rated</a>
              </div>
            </figcaption>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <h1 class="footer-title">Help</h1>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Contact</h1></a>
      <br>
      <a href="#"><h1 class="footer-txt">Terms of service</h1></a>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! By the way, do you know how to make the sections active when you click them? Again, thank you so much!!!

Comment: @CristianoViana, you're welcome. Yeah, I just made an edit to the post that adds this functionality. It just reads `data-open` attribute, styles the tab, and invokes `openTab`. Everything else is same

Comment: Thank you so much again for your time and kindness! Really!